# What is the Constantinopolitan hat incentivizing?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012

In my interpretation it will encourage posting noise questions here. Is there some legitimate reason for putting this hat in Winter Bash?

Comment: The irony... the irony...

Comment: ...what are *any* of the hats good for?

Comment: Fancy graphics :)

Comment: Oops, wrong tab. :-P I did not vote to close, no sir..

Comment: I really wish they hadn't made that hat.  It's just making meta fill up with spam and hat related questions...

Comment: Ain't dupe, you dope, I'm just asking about Constantinopolitan. :)

Comment: @Servy: As opposed to spam and questions related to not-hats?

Comment: @McCannot As opposed to interesting questions about what the standard guidelines should be for various situations; what should be encouraged or not encouraged, etc.  Adding all of this spam decreases the signal to noise ratio; it makes the interesting stuff harder to find

Comment: @Servy I had some hat related questions, but found the answers in the three questions there were by then. It seems to have exploded recently, however.

Comment: Wonder why it's called "Constantinopolitan" - they would have been more in vogue after Constantinople fell, no?

Comment: @Servy: I've got it! They just need to add a hat for deleting your own post on meta, and the problem will solve itself.

Comment: You don't know the half of it. The first version was a new-years-style noisemaker accessory awarded for getting 10 questions closed on Meta.

Comment: @Brendan Funny thing is, nobody get that hat's name right. It's actually "Constantipolitan". On the other question, they called it "Cosmopolitan", lol! As for the name: no ideal why they gave a pseudo-turkish name to a moroccan hat. Maybe it's just to confuse us.

Comment: @McCannot Maybe this is a grand experiment to see just how low people will stoop to get relatively meaningless rewards if given the chance!

Comment: @Brendan: I think I know where that experiment will lead. If there were a hat for "getting your account deleted" then SO would be a ghost town within a week.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Correct. I answered this post and got the hat.

Comment: @McCannot Brilliant. Not sure what the hat would be though...executioner's mask?

Comment: @Brendan: A pistol, held against the side of the avatar, with the name "Goodbye Cruel World". Or would that be too tasteless?

Comment: @McCannot Yeah...that might be pushing it. Perhaps a Strong Bad mask? "BA-leted!"

Comment: I was going to lay off the site over the holidays, but now I desperately want hats.  I am a ridiculous person.

Comment: @dbaseman: Correction: a ridiculous person *with hats*. Makes *all* the difference.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's just for fun, really, but in fact we do want to encourage more users to visit their meta, because so few do, and you can find out a lot about the culture of your site in its meta.

Comment: This^.  And yes, most "post" promotions require upvotes to prevent noise, but that's trickier on Meta, where downvotes often represent disagreement (whether that *should* be the case is another story).

Comment: @Jaydles <confused>Did you mean to post that under the question?

Comment: no.  I'm just augmenting your essentially correct answer.

Comment: @Jaydles Makes more sense now.</confused>

Comment: @AndrewC: Impeccable use of XML. I provide you One Meta Upvote, redeemable when I'm not vote capped :P

Comment: @Manishearth Thanks. This is my most upvoted meta post yet, and it took me past 1000 rep. Here's hoping I get rep capped for more exciting hats!

Comment: @AndrewC: 12 votes is your most upvoted meta post? 12? Your meta-life is sad. Out of pity, I grant you two more Meta Upvotes. Also, since your comment upvote above led me to getting my 15th hat (which triggered my 16th hat--earned when you get 15 hats), I grant you a yet-to-be determined amount of meta votes and [waffle votes](http://stackapps.com/questions/3344/waffle-vote-counter).

Comment: Superbly generous of you, @Manishearth. I do like waffles. I remember first having waffles at my auntie's house. They didn't look like much, but so deliciously waffly. Mmmmmmm.

Comment: @AndrewC: Btw, since you seem relatively new, [context for the waffles in-joke](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19480/178438). And yes, waffles are good! Full of waffly waffleness!

Answer (score 11):

Because fezzes are cool!

[image]

Comment: Bow ties are cool.

Comment: Bow tie is cooler than the Fez!

Comment: Stetsons are cool too!

Comment: @Keen [meeh not as cool as the fez and the bow tie ^_^](http://thedoctoriscool.com)

Comment: [Fezzes are cool](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvWYw0CnuSI)

Comment: @Jin yes, yes they are ^_^

Comment: Correct Spelling is cool too.

Comment: @Protectorone what is wrong with my spelling?

Comment: @amana `invlalid`? (You can blame The Cheezburger if you want, but you're still the one reposting it.)

Comment: @Protectorone lol I ddnt notice that

Comment: @amana While we're all being Meta—first hit for Googling "invlalid" is a StackOverflow question…

Answer (score 9):

Clearly it's to encourage this sort of thing:

[image: OMGPONIES]

Comment: That is not a **fez**!

Comment: Unicorn with rainbow. How cute.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Fixed!

Comment: @Scrooginator ahhhh **much** better!

Answer (score 4):

Can I keep a hat? Because last time I was told that... But this, this, it, it, it's a little hat...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was under the impression that Winter Bash is more for fun than anything.

But what do I know, I'm only answering to get the hat :) (answers count, right?)

Comment: I only asked to get the hat :) So this is fun of course :)

Comment: There's also a hat for comments!

Comment: Mmm, interesting point!

Comment: @Scrooginator Five comments, right?

Comment: @Scrooginator I thought you just needed to make 5 comments, but they have to be upvoted to count.

Comment: @Brendan Yes, but upvoted ones.

Comment: Comments upvoted? An injustice!

Comment: Wait they have to be upvoted? I missed that memo...

Comment: @Scrooginator It's not that much of an injustice; it's just to prevent people from spamming the system with pointless comments just to get the hat. Comments have to be good, helpful, clear and contribute to the discussion. We can't have arbitrary nonsense counting for a hat.

Comment: I got the comment hat without upvoted comments I think.

Comment: @AndrewC particularly not a hat as prestigious as "Howdy Pardner".

Comment: @AdamArold I'm not sure you did: [lowdown on the hat](http://winterba.sh/howdy-pardner)

Comment: @AdamArold If you got it you must have made a bunch of great comments without even realizing it!

Comment: I'm such a cosmopolitan guy then :D

Comment: @AdamArold Looks like the hat's gone to your head...

Comment: OH my head errrr mean bad!

Comment: I'm wearing the comment hat right now, thanks to you! :D

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that it's an attempt at keeping the low-value hat-related posts restricted to meta where they're relatively harmless instead of ending up elsewhere and diluting the value of the Q&A sites.

Comment: Well-excecuted, then!

Answer (score 2):

As the [Winterbash FAQ](http://winterba.sh/faq) says, this is just for **fun**. This hat in particular I guess is to get some traffic to the Meta sites. But in case you don't like them:

> **I hate hats! How do I get rid of them?**
>
> At the bottom of every page, there is a button labeled, "I Hate Hats!" This will turn off all hat-related events on all sites for you. You won't see people wearing hats, you won't be alerted when you earn a hat, and you won't be seen wearing a hat by any other users.

Comment: Fun? On Meta? You know we hate fun, right? ;)

Comment: But you will see a lot of hat-related or hat-inspired posts on meta

Comment: @KateGregory Meta meta meta meta... Meta.